# <out T> vs <T> in Generics

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

What is the difference between `<out T>` and `<T>`? For example:

```
public interface IExample<out T>
{
    ...
}
```

vs.

```
public interface IExample<T>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Good example would be  IObservable<T> and IObserver<T>, defined in system ns in mscorlib.  public interface IObservable<out T>, and  public interface IObserver<in T>. Similarly, IEnumerator<out T>, IEnumerable<out T>

Comment: The best explanation I met: https://agirlamonggeeks.com/2019/05/29/vs-in-generic-interfaces-contravariance-vs-covariance-the-easier-part-1/ .(< in T> <– means that T can be only passed as a parameter to a method; <out T> <– means that T can be only returned as method results )

Answer (score 279, accepted):

The `out` keyword in generics is used to denote that the type T in the interface is covariant.   See [Covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/index) for details.

The classic example is `IEnumerable<out T>`.  Since `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant, you're allowed to do the following:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;
```

The second line above would fail if this wasn't covariant, even though logically it should work, since string derives from object.  Before [variance in generic interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces) was added to C# and VB.NET (in .NET 4 with VS 2010), this was a compile time error.

After .NET 4, `IEnumerable<T>` was marked covariant, and became `IEnumerable<out T>`.  Since `IEnumerable<out T>` only uses the elements within it, and never adds/changes them, it's safe for it to treat an enumerable collection of strings as an enumerable collection of objects, which means it's *covariant*.

This wouldn't work with a type like `IList<T>`, since `IList<T>` has an `Add` method.   Suppose this would be allowed:

```
IList<string> strings = new List<string>();
IList<object> objects = strings;  // NOTE: Fails at compile time
```

You could then call:

```
objects.Add(7); // This should work, since IList<object> should let us add **any** object
```

This would, of course, fail - so `IList<T>` can't be marked covariant.

There is also, btw, an option for `in` - which is used by things like comparison interfaces.  `IComparer<in T>`, for example, works the opposite way.  You can use a concrete `IComparer<Foo>` directly as an `IComparer<Bar>` if `Bar` is a subclass of `Foo`, because the `IComparer<in T>` interface is *contravariant*.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Because `Image` is an abstract class ;)  You can do `new List<object>() { Image.FromFile("test.jpg") };` with no problems, or you can do `new List<object>() { new Bitmap("test.jpg") };` as well.  The problem with yours is that `new Image()` isn't allowed (you can't do `var img = new Image();` either)

Comment: a generic `IList<object>` is a bizarre example, if you want `object`s you don't need generics.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Aren't you contradicting your own answer in your comment?

Answer (score 83):

For remembering easily the usage of `in` and `out` keyword (also covariance and contravariance), we can image inheritance as wrapping:

```
String : Object
Bar : Foo
```

[image: in/out]

Comment: Isn't this the wrong way around? 
Contravariance = in = allows less derived types to be used in place of more derived.
/ Covariance = out = allows more derived types to be used in place of less derived.

Personally, looking at your diagram, I read it as the opposite of the that.

Comment: co **u** variant (: for me

Comment: Can we use them at the same time?

Comment: @SamShiles and technically, a derived type (`string`) should be "bigger" than its base type (`object`) because it _should_ have more members. So the image works if you just swap the types.

Answer (score 67):

consider,

```
class Fruit {}

class Banana : Fruit {}

interface ICovariantSkinned<out T> {}

interface ISkinned<T> {}
```

and the functions,

```
void Peel(ISkinned<Fruit> skinned) { }

void Peel(ICovariantSkinned<Fruit> skinned) { }
```

The function that accepts `ICovariantSkinned<Fruit>` will be able to accept `ICovariantSkinned<Fruit>` or `ICovariantSkinned<Banana>` because `ICovariantSkinned<T>` is a covariant interface and `Banana` is a type of `Fruit`,

the function that accepts `ISkinned<Fruit>` will only be able to accept `ISkinned<Fruit>`.

Answer (score 59):

"`out T`" means that type `T` is "covariant". That restricts `T` to appear only as a returned (outbound) value in methods of the generic class, interface or method. The implication is that you can cast the type/interface/method to an equivalent with a super-type of `T`.
E.g. `ICovariant<out Dog>` can be cast to `ICovariant<Animal>`.

Comment: I didn't realize that `out` enforces that `T` can be returned only, until I read this answer. The whole concept makes more sense now!

Answer (score 8):

From the link you posted....

> For generic type parameters, **the out keyword specifies that the type
>   parameter is covariant**.

**EDIT**: 
Again, from the link you posted

> For more information, see Covariance and Contravariance (C# and Visual Basic). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I think this screenshot from VS2022 is pretty descriptive - it says what sort of constraints this put on generics:

[image: generics variance constraing]

Comment: Screenshots of text are a terrible way to present text.

Comment: I disagree, cause it presents real VS IDE feedback. Feel free to edit my post @DavidW

Answer (score 2):

The simplest explanation I found is in this [article](https://agirlamonggeeks.com/2019/05/29/vs-in-generic-interfaces-contravariance-vs-covariance-the-easier-part-1/) stated as

> interface `ISomeName<in T>` <– means that T can be only passed as a
> parameter to a method (it enters inteface’s methods, so it goes
> inside, maybe that’s why we use here keyword ‘in’… Hmm, no, that’s
> just a coincidence ?)
>
> interface `ISomeName<out T>` <– means that T can be only returned as
> method results (it is what we receive from a method so it goes out of
> it – wow, again sounds legit!)

Answer (score 2):

###### covariant out

```cs
//I need a fruit farm(base class) so i can produce fruits(base type)
//But what I have is an apple farm(derived class) that produce apples (derive type)
IProducer<Apple> appleFarm = new AppleProducer(); 
//thats ok, I'll just mark it as covariant(out) since apple is also a fruit
IProducer<Fruit> fruitFarm = appleFarm; 

Apple apple = appleFarm.Produce();
//I can produce fruits since apple is a fruit
Fruit fruit = apple;
```

###### contravariant in

```cs
//I need an apple bakery(derive class) so i can use my apples(derive type)
//But what I have is a fruit bakery(base class) that uses fruits(base type)
IConsumer<Fruit> fruitBakery = new FruitConsumer();
//thats ok, I'll just mark it as contravariant(in) since a fruit bakery can also consume apples
IConsumer<Apple> appleBakery = fruitBakery;

//can consume apples and any fruits
appleBakery.Consume(new Apple());
fruitBakery.Consume(new Fruit());
fruitBakery.Consume(new Apple());
```

So basically:

- if you mark an interface generic as covariant, it must be able to **out**put the generic type, and it allows you to convert a derive type of the generic type into its base type.

```cs
IProducer<Apple> appleFarm = new AppleProducer(); 
IProducer<Fruit> fruitFarm = appleFarm; 

Apple apple = appleFarm.Produce();
Fruit fruit = apple;
```

- if you mark an interface generic as contravariant, it must be able to **in**put the generic type, and it allows you to convert a derive type of the generic type into its base type.

```cs
IConsumer<Fruit> fruitBakery = new FruitConsumer();
IConsumer<Apple> appleBakery = fruitBakery;

fruitBakery.Consume(new Apple());
fruitBakery.Consume(new Fruit());
appleBakery.Consume(new Apple());
```

To understand why, look up liskov subsitution principle.

full code:

```cs
public interface IProducer<out T>
{
    T Produce();
}
 
public class Fruit { }
 
public class Apple : Fruit { }
 
public class FruitProducer : IProducer<Fruit>
{
    public Fruit Produce() => new Fruit();
}
 
public class AppleProducer : IProducer<Apple>
{
    public Apple Produce() => new Apple();
}
 
public interface IConsumer<in T>
{
    void Consume(T item);
}
 
public class FruitConsumer : IConsumer<Fruit>
{
    public void Consume(Fruit item)
    {
        // Consume the fruit
    }
}
 
public class AppleConsumer : IConsumer<Apple>
{
    public void Consume(Apple item)
    {
        // Consume the apple
    }
}
```