# Register Keyed implementation with Autofac receiving an ArgumentException (Type X not assignable to service Y)

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I'm registering some concrete types using the Autofac Keyed options. This all appeared to be working fine until I added a generic parameter to the types and interface.

My registration looks like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<Customer.DataAccess.Database.StoreElasticConnectionManagerByCompany>();
builder.RegisterType<Customer.DataAccess.Database.StoreElasticConnectionManagerByStore>();
builder.RegisterType<Customer.DataAccess.Database.StoreElasticConnectionManager>();
builder.RegisterType<Customer.DataAccess.Database.DatabaseManagement>().As<IDatabaseManagement>();

builder.RegisterType<ConnectionManagerFactory<Customer.DataAccess.Database.StoreElasticConnectionManagerByStore>>()
    .Keyed<IConnectionManagerFactory<IConnectionManager>>(DatabaseConnectionShardingTypes.StoreDatabaseByStoreId);
builder.RegisterType<ConnectionManagerFactory<Customer.DataAccess.Database.StoreElasticConnectionManagerByCompany>>()
    .Keyed<IConnectionManagerFactory<IConnectionManager>>(DatabaseConnectionShardingTypes.StoreDatabaseByCompanyId);

builder.RegisterType<DatabaseManagement>().As<IDatabaseManagement>().SingleInstance();
```

The concrete types and interfaces are implemented like so:

```
/*The factories*/
public interface IConnectionManagerFactory<T>
        where T : IConnectionManager 
{}

public class ConnectionManagerFactory<T> : IConnectionManagerFactory<T>
        where T : IConnectionManager
{}
/*The Connection Manager*/
public interface IConnectionManager
{}
public abstract class StoreElasticConnectionManager : IConnectionManager
{}
public class StoreElasticConnectionManagerByStore : StoreElasticConnectionManager
{}
```

When I'm trying to run my code (when the registration is executing) I'm receiving the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   Autofac.dll
>
> Additional information: The type
>   'Customer.DataAccess.Database.ConnectionManagerFactory`1[Customer.DataAccess.Database.StoreElasticConnectionManagerByStore]'
>   is not assignable to service 'StoreDatabaseByStoreId
>   (Customer.DataAccess.Database.IConnectionManagerFactory`1[[Customer.DataAccess.Database.IConnectionManager,
>   Customer.DataAccess.Database, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]])'.

This is probably due to the fact I've added the generic parameter to the `ConnectionManagerFactory`, because it worked before I did this.

I've tried adding the following:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Customer.DataAccess.Database.ConnectionManagerFactory<>))
                                                    .As(typeof(IConnectionManagerFactory<>));
```

But this didn't appear to solve the issue.

Any advice on how to proceed?

**edit**

In response to nemesv's question, this is the code which works and where I'm not using generics

```
builder.RegisterType<Customer.DataAccess.Database.StoreElasticConnectionManagerByCompany>();
                builder.RegisterType<Customer.DataAccess.Database.StoreElasticConnectionManagerByStore>();
                builder.RegisterType<Customer.DataAccess.Database.StoreElasticConnectionManager>();

                builder.RegisterType<ConnectionManagerFactory<Customer.DataAccess.Database.StoreElasticConnectionManagerByStore>>()
                                .Keyed<IConnectionManagerFactory>(DatabaseConnectionShardingTypes.StoreDatabaseByStoreId);
                builder.RegisterType<ConnectionManagerFactory<Customer.DataAccess.Database.StoreElasticConnectionManagerByCompany>>()
                                .Keyed<IConnectionManagerFactory>(DatabaseConnectionShardingTypes.StoreDatabaseByCompanyId);
```

As you can see, the interface `IConnectionManagerFactory` isn't generic anymore.

The concrete `ConnectionManagerFactory` now looks like this:

```
public class ConnectionManagerFactory<T> : IConnectionManagerFactory
        where T : IConnectionManager
```

The `DatabaseConnectionShardingTypes` is a simple enum.

I've solved my issue now by changing the code a bit and not using generics anymore, but I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong in the above example.

Comment: What is the type of `DatabaseConnectionShardingTypes.StoreDatabaseByStoreId`? How did the your working registration looked before adding the generic paramter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cast a `ConnectionManagerFactory<StoreElasticConnectionManagerByStore>` to a `IConnectionManagerFactory<IConnectionManager>`

You have to specify that your interface is covariant to allow such cast, you do it with the `out` modifier (see ["out T" vs. "T" in Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956993/out-t-vs-t-in-generics) for more information)

```
public interface IConnectionManagerFactory<out T>
        where T : IConnectionManager
{ }
```

If you try the following line of code you will obtain a compilation error :

```
ConnectionManagerFactory<StoreElasticConnectionManagerByStore>  c = null;
IConnectionManagerFactory<IConnectionManager> i = (ConnectionManagerFactory<StoreElasticConnectionManagerByStore>)c;
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConnectionManagerFactory' to 'IConnectionManagerFactory'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Adding the `out` modifier implies that your interface can't accept a `T` within a method parameter :

```
public interface IConnectionManagerFactory<out T>
        where T : IConnectionManager
{
    void Do1(T t); // not valid 
    T Do2();       // valid
}
```

If your `IConnectionManagerFactory<T>` is not covariant, you will have to change your code by splitting your interface for example