# C# Inheritance containing another inheritable object?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have the following objects

```
class Magazine 
{ 
    String intendedGunId {get;}//Returns some Gun.weaponID;
    int size {get;}
    //Implementation
}

class Gun 
{
    public enum FireModes
    {
        Bolt,
        Semi,
        FullAuto
    }

    public FireModes fireMode { get; private set; }

    Magazine magazine;

    public Magazine reload(Magazine newMag)
    {
        if (magazine.intendedGunId == newMag.intendedGunID)
        {
            Magazine temp = magazine;
            this.magazine = newMag;
            return temp;
        }

         return newMag;
    }

    //Other implementation
 }

class AKMag : Mag
{
   //Implementation
}

class AK : Gun
{
   //Implementation
}
```

I am designing a gun and a magazine that should always be used in said gun for multiple different guns.

I don't think keeping the Magazine variable as `T : Magazine` instead of just Magazine is a smart idea, as when reloading, nearly any magazine could be accepted, and it doesn't feel like safe code; I feel like a hacker could easily take advantage of this.

I have tried the following generic:

```
class Gun<T> where T : Magazine
{
    T magazine;
    //Other implementation
}

class AK : Gun<AKMag>
{

}
```

The problem is once I use generics, it becomes impossible to store a `Gun<Magazine>` variable, because at some point, the compiler will say "Can not convert from `Gun<AKMag>` to `Gun<T> where T : Magazine`.

Basically, every gun has its own mag that will only belong to it's gun. I am struggling to implement this correctly, maybe from a lack of understanding of C# generics or C# inheritance.

EDIT:
With a gun generic, the following scenario does not work:

```
Gun<Magazine> someGun;

public void func (Gun<Magazine> gun)
{
    this.someGun = gun;
}

//In another class

AK<AKMagazine> someAK;

public void func2 ()
{
    func1 (someAK);  //Error: "Can not convert from `Gun<AKMag>` to `Gun<T> where T : Magazine`."
}
```

Edit: I decided that the best way to do this was to check if magazine.GetType() == newMag.GetType() whenever the mag was going to be change, however an interface may work as well.

Comment: share the code that makes the compiler complain. I can't understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: Create an `IGun` interface, implement it in `Gun<T>` and store your guns in variable typed as `IGun`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, may I ask you for a little bit more detail? I think I understand, but I am not sure exactly how I would do that. Ill add more information to the Gun class as I am not sure an Interface will work.

Comment: Maybe it helps to make `T` covariant - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956993/out-t-vs-t-in-generics

Comment: @Ruud, while that seems like it would work, it requires an interface. I'll have to try to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

What about just using plain old Interface?

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Gun myGun = new AK();
            Console.WriteLine(myGun.load(new AK_Mag())); // true
            Console.WriteLine(myGun.load(new ShotGun_Mag())); // false
            func2();
        }

        static Gun someGun;
        static void func1(Gun gun)
        {
            someGun = gun; 
        }

        public static void func2()
        {
            Gun someAK = new AK();
            someAK.load(new AK_Mag());
            func1(someAK);
        }
    }

    public class AK : Gun
    {
        public bool load(Mag mag)
        {
            if (mag == null)
                return false;
            if ( mag.GetType() != typeof(AK_Mag))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public void shoot(int x, int y, int z)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool setFireMode(Gun.FireMode mode)
        {
            this.mode = mode;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class AK_Mag : Mag
    {
        public int Remain()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class ShotGun_Mag : Mag
    {
        public int Remain()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public interface Gun
    {
        public enum FireMode { Manual, Burst };
        bool load(Mag mag);
        void shoot(int x, int y, int z);
        bool setFireMode(FireMode mode);        
    }

    public interface Mag
    {
        int Remain();
    }
```

Comment: I can give it a shot, but then I have to deal with where to put the FireMode enum.

Comment: My opinion is to put that enum in your implemented gun class.

Comment: Make `interface Gun` generic and the `mag.GetType() != typeof(AK_Mag)` check would not be needed anymore.

Comment: @TLJ, The enum exists for all guns however.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance of generic type parameters does not involve inheritance of the generic class. I think that generics are not the right solution here.

Try this approach:

```
class Magazine
{
    public readonly Type GunType; // Used for identification of compatible gun type.

    public Magazine (Type gunType)
    {
        this.GunType = gunType;
    }
}

class Gun
{
    // Factory method
    public Magazine CreateMagazine()
    {
        return new Magazine(this.GetType());
    }

    public Magazine Reload(Magazine newMag)
    {
        // Test whether the magazine is compatible with the current gun.
        if (newMag.GunType != this.GetType()) {
            throw new ArgumentException();
            // Or just reject the new magazine and keep the current one.
        }

        // Your reload logic goes here ...
    }
}
```

The problem with the generics is that two types `T<A>` and `T<B>` are not assignment compatible, even when there is an inheritance relationship between `A` and `B`. The other problem is, that generics are fully resolved at compile time. You need a more dynamic approach here. In a game you might want to store guns and magazines in the user's inventory and handle all the gun and magazine types the same way. Storing the required type as `System.Type` can be done at runtime in a fully dynamic way.

You would create and work with magazines like this:

```
Gun gun = new AK();
Magazine magazine = gun.CreateMagazine();
Magazine other = gun.Reload(magazine);
```

Comment: I will test this now, and let you know. At first glance it looks good!

Comment: The compiler is now telling me AKMag is a type and is not, which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: Please explain your error message. Note that `this.GetType()` returns a class of type `System.Type` which describes the gun classes. It is not a gun class itself.