# C# Generic Interface Type returning Null

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-core, .net-standard

I've got a class `Table`, which returns a collection of `Entity`, such as:

```
Table<Song> table = database.GetTable("SongCollection");
```

Where `Song` is a subclass `Entity`. `Table` also implements an interface `ITable` and `Entity` implements an interface called `IEntity`.

However, calling:

```
ITable<IEntity> table = database.GetTable("SongCollection");
```

or

```
ITable<Entity> table = database.GetTable("SongCollection");
```

or

```
Table<Entity> table = database.GetTable("SongCollection");
```

or

```
Table<IEntity> table = database.GetTable("SongCollection");
```

All return null.

I can call `table.GetAll()` and return a `List<Song>` and cast each individual `Song` to an `IEntity` just fine.

What should I be doing in the case of the `Table` though so that I don't have to return a `List<dynamic>` in order to get the `Table` when making for example an administrative interface for doing CRUD operations on all `Tables` generically?

Comment: Show us the function.

Comment: Because none of those 4 types (`ITable<IEntity>`, `ITable<Entity>`, `Table<IEntity>`, `Table<Entity>`) is the same as `Table<Song>` which is what is returned by `GetTable`. These generic type definitions are not marked as covariant which. If it the generic type was read-only you could mark it as covariant (with `out` keyword).

Comment: See also [<out T> vs <T> in Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10956993/1260204)

Comment: I just tried that, and so once I changed ITable's definition to public interface ITable<out T> where T : IEntity, it causes errors on some of the methods of the interface in regards to variance. List<T> GetAll(); gives an error about invariance, void LoadRelated(T current); gives an error about contravariance. Do those need to be split into separate interfaces? It would appear that I have some covariant, invariant, and contravariant methods in my interface declaration.

Comment: Correct. If you want to know why think about this. What would happen if this was possible and you got a `Table<Entity>` instance which was actually of type `Table<Song>` and then you did `table.Add(new SomethingOtherThanSong());` That would break type safety that c# provides. This is why the type must be covariant, it states that you can't make changes to the collection and ensures that casting `Table<T>`  won't cause an error as it will not allow modification of the collection.

Comment: That's a good point I never want to be in a situation where types could be mixed in the same table. Is there a solution for this problem, or is it best to leave it alone and just use a var when calling GetTable (which I do in the controller for the CRUD functions right now), of course I then have to cast my GetAll for records to a List<dynamic> or var which is unfavorable but at least works. I was hoping to be able to cast to something like ITable<IEntity> so that I could at least get the benefits of Intellisense on methods.

Comment: I just tried creating a separate ITable<in T> to separate my contravariant methods and of course that fails as a duplicate name.

Comment: You could extend your existing interface to also implement existing interfaces `IEnumerable<T>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. Then you could cast to that type instead.

Comment: That works for methods that return a List<T> I can change those to IEnumerable<T>. It doesn't the methods that take either T or a generic collection of T as a parameter though, either as mentioning that the method is invariant or contravariant. Is there a solution that allows them to be part of the same interface, or would they have to be separated out into new interfaces with new names?

Comment: For example, on ITable there's a method void LoadRelated(T current); that I wrote to load any Parent and Child entities for a given IEntity that's invariant.

Comment: You're absolutely right that it's the Invariant methods that are causing it to return null. I just split them out into an ITableInvariant<T> and ITableCovariant<T>, and the covariant returns an interface, of course that interface doesn't have the GetAll method which returns all entities for a table as a List<T>. The invariant returns null. I may want to add to a List<T> collection though so it imposes a big problem that I'm not sure how to solve exactly, because I obviously don't want records of a different type of IEntity to be added to a table different from the original type created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was actually pretty weird and thank you Igor for helping guide me in the right direction.

So I did change my output types from `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` without any major blowups in my code, my end interface looked something like so:

```
public interface ITable<out T> where T : IEntity {
    string TableName { get; set; }
    Database CurrentDatabase { get; set; }

    T New();
    T Get(ulong id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();

    void LoadAllStorageFiles(IEnumerable<IEntity> storage);
    void StoreAllStorageFiles(IEnumerable<IEntity> storage);
    void LoadRelated(IEntity current);
    void LoadRelated(IEnumerable<IEntity> current);
}
```

When I separated out my Covariant methods and Invariant, originally Contravariant, methods into different interface types, the covariant would cast and the contravariant would become null during cast.

Here's the part that's weird, these were my original Contravariant methods:

```
    void LoadAllStorageFiles(IEnumerable<T> storage);
    void StoreAllStorageFiles(IEnumerable<T> storage);
    void LoadRelated(T current);
    void LoadRelated(IEnumerable<T> current);
```

Now you would think that making the typing more strict to only accept the same generic type as the rest of the Table would make implicit sense. In this case though, at runtime it's seen as contravariant and the runtime just gives up and gives you null without an exception. In this case, making the parameters to LoadRelated and so on IEntity rather than T, no matter how Twilight Zone'ish in that you've now made it less strict because now the parameter has opened up to any IEntity, which seems I think to show a point that maybe some exception should be made hypothetically to the runtime environment in certain contravariant cases, but would possibly take more code, effort, and money than it's worth to satisfy such a problem, satisfies the runtime environment's checking and you're able to move on without a hitch.

So I'm only noting here for anyone else who encounters this situation and shrugs a bit. Maybe someone can shed some light in the comments.