# C# Access to implicit operators of base class

Tags: c#, oop, implicit-conversion

I have the following setup: `Entity` is deriving from `MonoBehaviour`.
MonoBehaviour implements an implizit conversion to bool. Now if I implement an implicit conversion to bool in Entity, it overrides the one from MonoBehaviour.
If I now want to access both the old and the new conversion, I have to do cast back to the base class

```
public class Entity : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    private float CurrentHealthPoints { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator bool(Entity entity) 
        => (MonoBehaviour)entity && entity.CurrentHealthPoints > 0;
}
```

Now my question, is there a different method without having to cast to the base class? I tried to use the `base` keyword, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, unless the type being used utilizes [contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/index), the explicit casting is inevitable. You can make use of [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956993/out-t-vs-t-in-generics) too.

Comment: How can I find out if it is, or how can I set it to be covariant or contravariant?

Comment: @harlekintiger seemingly, you cannot apply it to your case since they are not generic. So, the fact that your hands have tied coerces you to use the explicit casting.